# Why does the Netbeans designer set the JFrame size to something different than I specified?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-8

In the netbeans designer, every frame and panel I'm using is set to [415,330], but when I run the program it looks like the window is still set to [400,300] or something close to that. I'm changing the minimum, maximum and preferred size. Do I need to do something else?

EDIT: Restarted netbeans and the problem fixed itself.

Comment: Could we see some code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: A frame has borders, the preferred/min/max size doesn't take those into account and the viewable are is been set to meet yr requirements then the frame is likely been added around it....

Comment: @MadProgrammer If the viewable area was set to meet my requirements why is the window smaller than what I set?

Comment: Probably because it's been packed to meet the requirements of the content. Best bet. Ditch the form editor and hand code your UI's until you understand how the API fits together

Comment: @MadProgrammer So it will just set itself to however big it needs to be to fit all the components on the screen? It was doing that before and I solved it by just setting a label with no text to the position I want to my screen to be. I just tried that now and the screen was set back to the same size as before.

Comment: *"I'm changing the minimum, maximum and preferred size."*  See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you've set the size with `minimumSize` and `preferredSize`, you might have forgotten to call `Window.pack()` in which Swing will resize the components (and all of it's subcomponents) according to the sizes set.

You call it in your window (or whatever is building your window) after all the preferred sizes are set.

Comment: I found this out back when I asked the question, but this ended up being the solution!